# Java - New Object definition reading old objects

Tags: java, class, object

Not sure if the title is appropriate, but here is my question

I wrote a class, for example,

**version 1**

```
class SomeClass
{
    public method1()
    {
        ...
        ...
    }

    public method2()
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The objects of SomeClass are pushed to a message queue by different modules say

```
module1
module2
module3
```

which then is being processed `module4`

Now, `module3` requires some additional functionality method3() so I added additional functionality to SomeClass

**version 2**

```
class SomeClass
{
    public method1()
    {
        ...
        ...
    }

    public method2()
    {
        ...
        ...
    }

    public method3()
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

and updated `module3` and `module 4` with this new class, however module1 and module2 are not

`module3` will post objects of `SomeClass` (version 2) to the message queue, however `module1` and `module2` still post objects of `SomeClass` (version 1)

Will there be any problems for `module 4` that has version 2 definition to read the objects of version 1 definition?

Comment: How are the objects represented in the message queue?

Comment: Are you adding members or just functions ? And how are you persisting/serialising these objects ?

Comment: Objects are being posted to the message queue using JMS (JMSTemplate in Spring) to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it could work because when you push object to message queue (using `ObjectMessage`) it is serialized using standard java serialization mechanism. Serialization does not care about methods. It uses fields only. It means that you can serialize object v1 and then deserialze it using class version 2. But I believe you will have to add special field `private static long serialVersionUID` to your class and manage its value manually.

So, your v1 and v2 that have identical number and order of field and differ by methods only will have the same `serialVersionUID`.